# BigQuery - Count non-nulls across columns where the column name matches regex patterns

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, re2

Very new to BQ so please be patient.

I have a table with various columns (in the example they are col1 to col4 for brevity) and I have a regex that determines which column names are to be grouped together (example - ac_v\d+_final_p\w+).  What I want to do is identify how many times non-null values appear within the grouping of columns for a specific row.  From research, I was able to craft the attached query, however, this obviously only returns the count across the entire table and not the rows associated with the defined regex as desired.

**Simplified Data Structure:**

| key | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | lol1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0.0025 | null | null | null | null |
| 3 | 0.0015 | null | 0.0005 | null | null |
| 1 | null | null | null | 0.000 | 0.3 |

**Desired Outcome:**
I want to count only those columns with the col name prefix.

| key | count_non_nulls | count_nulls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

Is there a way to achieve this in BQ Standard SQL?

Thank you in anticipation of your help.

```
BEGIN
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP TABLE `mytable` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS key, null AS col1, null AS col2, null AS col3, 0.0001 AS col4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 0.0025, null, null, null UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 0.0015,  null, 0.0005, null
)
;

SELECT 
  COUNTIF(value not in  ('null', '')) AS count_non_nulls, 
  COUNTIF(value in  ('null', '')) AS count_nulls, 
  COUNT(value) count_all
FROM `mytable` t, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'":(.*?)(?:,"|})')) value
;

END
```

Comment: not clear! can  you provide better example with expected output

Comment: Hi Mikhail.  Updated with the desired outcome.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select key, 
  (
    select as struct 
      countif(column_value != 'null') as count_non_nulls,
      countif(column_value = 'null') as count_nulls
    from unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv,
    unnest([struct(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] as column_name, split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as column_value)])
    where column_name != 'key'
    and starts_with(column_name, 'col')
  ).*
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: if you need to use whatever regex you have - you can use it instead of below line

```
starts_with(column_name, 'col')
```

Comment: Brilliant Mikhail.  Thank you for your help.